# How does Facebook know it is the real app when calling the Graph API using Javascript?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When calling the new Facebook Graph API, if we just provide the `app_id` in the Javascript code, then how can Facebook know it is the real app calling?  What if it is another app calling with that `app_id`?

Answer (score 1):

You set your site domain in app properties, if you try to call api from other domains it wouldn't work.

Comment: so you need to make sure it works with   www1.site.com, www2.site.com, etc?  (maybe it accepts a `site.com` domain and work with any subdomain?)

Comment: @Jian yes it works with subdomains. If you go to app setting it is explained there under this field.